# PANA authentication agent

Tags: security, authentication, networking, contiki

i am implementing the zigbee ip spec on contiki, and so I am trying to work my way through pana and eap-tls. I've started my work with already available software like panatiki and openpana, however the UDP payload in openpana is quite large compared to the uip application data buffer. I tried reducing the buffer size of openpana, but it always ends up in seg fault whenever it is kept anything below 2048(I've not checked all, but I did checked with 1024 and it didn't work). Any suggestions on some alternative pana authentication agent that will operate with freeradius as backend authentication server?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution of this problem. Besides resizing the buffer size of openpana as found in mainserver.h file, it is also required to reconfigure the freeradius server to have a smaller fragment size, by editing the eap.conf file. In ubuntu this file is found in /etc/freeradius/eap.conf and one needs to assign a new value to fragment_size parameter. The freeradius server must be restarted for the change to take effect, by doing:

```
sudo service freeradius restart
```